# How to use a default routes for login screen - Angular 4

Tags: angular

How to use a default routes for login screen - Angular 4

I want to load the login screen inside the "mw-root" tag and not inside the outlet.

Is it possible to understand? Right now, I'm grateful for your attention.

Router

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent  },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'download', component: DownloadComponent },
    { path: 'compare', component: CompareComponent }
]
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MW</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>
<body>

  <mw-root></mw-root>

</body>
</html>
```

app.component

```
<div class="all-wrapper menu-side with-side-panel">
  <div class="layout-w">

    <mw-side-menu class="desktop-menu menu-side-w menu-activated-on-click"></mw-side-menu>
    <div class="content-w">
      <mw-header-menu></mw-header-menu>
      <div class="content-i">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is all about the structure of your project you can take 2 modules, and each module got template, see how this project built: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/tree/master/src/app

Comment: Hi, When executing the login route, in this case, how do I open it in the "mw-root" tag? Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One quick way I can think of is to change the structure of your routes to something like this:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
   {
      path: '',
      component: MainComponent,
      children: [
         { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
         { path: 'download', component: DownloadComponent },
         { path: 'compare', component: CompareComponent }
      ] 
   },
   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
]
```

The key here is that the Routes can have children which is an array of Routes as you can see.

Your app.component.html can look like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Notice we only place router-outlet, which will hold the view for either MainComponent or LoginComponent, which can be separate

Then in MainComponent:

```
<div class="all-wrapper menu-side with-side-panel">
  <div class="layout-w">

    <mw-side-menu class="desktop-menu menu-side-w menu-activated-on-click"></mw-side-menu>
    <div class="content-w">
      <mw-header-menu></mw-header-menu>
      <div class="content-i">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Notice this is the same as before. There is another router-outlet which refers to the routes of the nested children in MainComponent. Views from HomeComponent, DownloadComponent, and CompareComponent will go in here.

Cheers!

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you very much.